# jquery use variables in selector not working

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

When i try to do this:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  current_page = window.location.hash;
}
$(current_page).siblings('.page').css(display: 'none');
```

current_page would be e.g `#hello`, so i dont think removing the `#` is necessary, since i am using ID's to identify the element.

This is my error in chrome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token:`
I don't get more than that.

I've read other questions on here about how to use variables in selectors, and it should work. I've also rewritten it twice to make sure there's no hidden characters.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Well what's in window.location.hash? -> `console.log(window.location.hash)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's not:

```
.css(display: 'none');
```

but

```
.css('display', 'none');
```

or

```
.css({display: 'none'});
```

or

```
.hide()
```

Comment: Argh, thought it was something wrong with the variable. Accepting as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax inside the css() call is wrong, use this:

```
$(current_page).siblings('.page').css('display', 'none');
```